# An example of $(x_{n})$ such that one of $\prod(1+x_{n})$ or $\sum x_{n}$ is convergent the other is not

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have considered taking, $x_{n}=(-1)^{n}/n$, then by the alternating series test it can be shown that :

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n} \quad \text{is convergent}$$

while the product

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\bigg) \quad \text{diverges to zero} $$
where $p_{n}=(1+(-1)/1)\cdots (1+(-1)^{n}/n)=0 \implies p_{n}\to 0$ therefore divergent to zero

is the example correct ?

Comment: Just because a limit goes to zero does not mean it is divergent; in fact, a limit going to zero is convergent. A limit diverges only when the limit does not exist, or (up to your definition) when it is infinite

Comment: In terms of products, we add an extra notion of divergence which states that if the limit of the partial products tends to zero, we say that a product diverges to $0$, in the question it's not implied that divergence need be to infinity or that it doesn't exist

Comment: The exercice is clearly not asking for a product whose first term is $0$.

Comment: The exercice is asking to showcase existence, it's a followup to the theorem relating convergence of the product $(1+x_{n})$ and the sum $(x_{n})$, for $x_{n}\geq 0$, where is it clearly not asking for a product whose first term is $0$. the point of it is to showcase that if a sequence is alternating then the theorem need not hold

Comment: @Eulerroid: your example is not that interesting since one term in the product is $0$. Now, if you remove that term, you end up with $\prod^\infty_{n=1}(1+\tfrac{(-1)^{n+1}} {n+1})\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$. Of course $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$ converges (conditionally). In this case both the product and the series converge conditionally.

Comment: @Eulerroid: If $0<a_n<1$ and $\sum_na_n=\infty$ then $\prod_n(1-a_n)$ diverges to $0$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz yeah you are right, in terms of it being interesting its not interesting, but I was just trying to come with a simple  example that gets the job done as quick as possible, and the theorem you have written  holds due to Cauchy convergence criteria not being true  ?

Comment: Divergence (to $0$) follows from $1-a_n<e^{-a_n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has appeared here before, but it is not easy to search.

Here is an example.
$$
x_n = -1+\exp((-1)^n/\sqrt{n})
\\
x_n = -1 + \left(1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2n}+O(n^{-3/2})\right)
\\
\sum_{n=1}^N x_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}
+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^N O(n^{-3/2})
\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\quad\text{diverges to } +\infty.
$$
On the other hand
$$
1+x_n = \exp((-1)^n/n^{1/2})
\\
\log(1+x_n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/2}}
\\
\sum\log(1+x_n)\quad\text{ converges}
\\
\prod(1+x_n) = \exp \sum\log(1+x_n)\quad\text{ converges}
$$